# Does the Crystal created by Astral Seed violate Vow of Poverty?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, psionics

Does the crystal created by the power [*Astral Seed*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/astralSeed.htm) count as a possession that would violate [*Vow of Poverty*](http://marksworld.zeemer.com/files/feats/featlibrary/vowofpoverty.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have asked enough questions on the subject of Vow of Poverty to know how this is going to go: *Book of Exalted Deeds* is rather unclear, and all available commentary on the subject is basically “if you have to ask, the answer is no.”  Vow of Poverty is poorly written, poorly considered, poorly designed, and should never be used—this glib kind of short-shrift given to corner-cases is perfectly consistent with the writing of *Book of Exalted Deeds* on the subject. By that metric, a storage crystal created by *astral seed* violates the Vow.

Rules as written, the feat says you may not have “any material possessions,” with only a few exceptions. A storage crystal is not on that list of exceptions. Is a storage crystal a “material possession”? *Who knows?* But again, I’m inclined to say it probably is—after all, it’s a physical object, not a psionic effect. *Astral seed* is instantaneous, which means it creates something that remains after the psionic effect has ended. The storage crystal would not be wiped out by *null psionics field*, for that matter, it even works in a *null psionics field* (as would a psicrystal). It’s an object. That seems like a “material possession” to me, so I would rule it as such.

You know, stipulating that I would allow Vow of Poverty at all, which I wouldn’t.

Comment: *And* the *seed* effect is also probably magical, and a dude with the Vow "may not use any magic item of any sort."

Comment: @KRyan What about the 9th level ability of the Psicrystal Imprinter prestige class that lets your psicrystal act as the soul receptacle for Astral Seed?

Comment: @Cellheim Why are you asking me? Your DM is the only one who has an answer to that question that is actually relevant to you. RAW is definitely not clear on whether or not a psicrystal is a “material possession.” More than enough room to argue it’s not, RAW, if that’s what you want. But I’m not sure why that’s relevant to anyone.

Comment: I highly agree with Ryan about VoP. But damn, Hey I Can Chan kills any doubt here - it is a magical Item. It makes sense to carry something that is used in daily life and not valuable with this vow - basic clothing, maybe some cheap weapons such as staves, some food, in sum, survival basic stuff. But this is a crystal. Not only that, but created WITH magic. If the vow of poverty tells that you won't carry anything you don't need and has value, surely an item created by a high level psi power is *not* a must-have item for your daily life, even if it has no estimated worth by the rules.

Comment: @KRyan You provided an answer to my question so I was asking about your interpretation of a related situation. I understand that it's up to my DM but I wanted a general idea of how others feel about the situation and can perhaps gain an understanding on how something works.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Does it matter that the astral seed is described as "totally inert" before your soul occupies it?

Comment: @Cellheim Well, like I said, realistically what I would do is not use Vow of Poverty at all in my game, so any answer I give to that question is pretty hypothetical. Anyway, it being inert or not doesn’t matter. It being *magical* or not doesn’t really matter, either—it probably is, but even if not you still probably aren’t allowed it. The only way around the Vow is to have it not be a material possession at all—which is maybe true for the psicrystal imprinter, but almost certainly not for anyone else.

Comment: @Cellheim If the power, instead, were *create dead monkey*, and all the power did was create was a dead monkey—y'know, an *inert* one—, a dude with the feat Vow of Poverty *still* couldn't lug around that dead monkey 'cause a dead monkey is Not. On. The. List.

Comment: @HeyICanChan So what you're saying is that a Hadozee StP Erudite with VoP couldn't manifest "Clone"?